# How Can I impute every column in a dataframe with its respective class mean?

Tags: python, pandas, mean, imputation

If I have two groups, 0 and 1 in a column labeled "Group Label", how can I impute the class mean for every other column based on that group, not based on the mean of the entire column

This is the code I have so far, which is splitting the DF into two groups but is not calculating the correct mean:

```
df1 = df.groupby("group_label").transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

Also, it seems to be dropping string columns such as my ID column.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `.transform('mean')` together with grouped DataFrame within `.fillna()`, but you would need to specify columns you want to apply to:

```py
# for a single column
df['col1'] = df['col1'].fillna(
    df.groupby('Group_Label')['col1'].transform('mean'))

# for multiple columns
df[['col1', 'col2', ...]] = df[['col1', 'col2', ...]].fillna(
    df.groupby('Group_Label')[['col1', 'col2', ...]].transform('mean'))
```

Comment: Thanks - in this case it's not possible to name the columns because there are ~13500 - is there another method?

Comment: @jw32022 use `list(df.columns)` so you don't need to name them...